# Practical numerical example illustrating how bayesian p-values should be used for model checking?

Tags: bayesian, p-value, misspecification

Can you give a practical numerical example illustrating how bayesian p-values should be used for model checking?

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions at once. You seem to be asking someone to write a full tutorial on using Bayesian p-values, rather then asking a specific question.

Comment: Great, that's much more clear question! Please consider however that previously you seem to have asked completely different question, that already got answered. The unwritten etiquette of this site is that we do not change the questions that already got answered, because people already made the effort trying to answer them. This basically discourages people from answering your questions and questions in general. I would suggest rather making the current version of the question a *new* question and keeping this the "How do I judge whether a "Bayesian p-value" is 'small enough'?" question.

Comment: @Tim I already asked the other question on this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/471085/bayesian-p-values-part-2-what-type-of-information-do-you-use-for-assessing-whe maybe Demetri can just move his answer to that one? Although this answer is not really answering anything, as I said, he is just saying "it depends".

Comment: Just to further clarify that Demetri's answer was not answering the original question: the original question asked "How do I judge"; Demetri answered with "it depends." Clearly, "it depends" does not explain "how."

Answer (score 5):

I've seen you post some questions pretty frequently looking for guidelines (e.g. how do I know when this is good enough).  That's great and an excellent attitude, but I think you're going to be frustrated with a lot of Bayesian Stats because the answer will more often than not be "it depends".

And this answer is no different.  The posterior probability that you observe data at least as extreme as some value is not a hard and fast rule as it is in Frequentism.  In my own experience, I don't use this quantity in isolation.  I instead loop in subject matter experts and ask them targeted questions.  For example, I might ask "how many patients out of 100 might have a max concentration: larger than $C$?  The subject matter expert will give me some approximation which I can then use to check my models.  But the important part here is that I could not know that number *a priori*, and so there is no "small enough" for every situation.

It heavily depends on what you're doing and what is important to you.

Comment: Thanks Demetri, but I'm not asking for a number that *a priori* will serve for all purposes. If you want to illustrate with context how you decided 5% was small, please provide the contextual information you used.

Comment: The problem of this type of answer is that you can answer anything like this... "Is this model for COVID-19 good? Well it depends on what you want to do with it." Yes, everyone know it depends. But what does it depend on? Can you show how *you* would use Bayesian p-values in a real (or at least in a toy) problem?

Comment: @BayesianNewbie Maybe after I talk with my pharmacologist friend she says "Its very rare to see someone with a drug concentration over 50 ng/ml 2 hours after taking a bolus dose".  After some badgering, I maybe get her to admit that fewer than 5 our of 100 people would have this measurement.  So from my posterior predictive distribution, I generate new observations.  If 5% (5/100) have a concentration larger than 50 ng/ml, then I might say that my model seems to replicate important aspects about whatever I'm modelling.

Comment: You might want to use this quantity in order to make sure your model predicts important parts about the population you are modelling.  If my model predicted that some patients would have normal concentrations, but some patients would have excessive amounts of drug in their blood, then that is a problem.  These "Bayesian p values" are a good way to check that your model captures important aspects about prevalence in the population.

Comment: It isn't *really* prior elicitation.  What we're doing is checking the model against known important properties of the thing we're modelling.  You could also use this with your data and ask "well, in my data I see fewer than 5 people out of 100 have this extreme measurement. If I sample 100 pseudo people from my model, do I continue to see this?"  If no, that might be a sign your model is missing something.

Comment: Well, no not really.  If my model captures something about my phenomena for which i did not explicitly tell it about, *then doesn't that sound like my model has learned something?*

Comment: Ok, can you show in practice this example then, so there are no ambiguities left? Here everyone is left wondering what you really mean, whereas if you show how you would do it then there would be no doubt about what you mean.

Comment: @BayesianNewbie **please avoid** lengthy discussions in comments. Comments are not meant for discussions.

Comment: @Tim I'm not discussing, my comments here are being used to ask for clarification and point out problems in the post.

Comment: @BayesianNewbie under many answers to your questions you seem to be asking many follow-up questions in comments, this may suggest that you are not making your question specific enough, what makes it hard for people to give you the kind of answers that you'd expect.

Comment: @BayesianNewbie I'm not really sue what you want out of an answer.  "Show me how you do it" is not really specific.  I'm happy to edit my answer and invest my time when you edit your question to unambiguously say what you would expect and what you would accept as an answer.

Comment: What is unclear about: "give a practical numerical example illustrating how bayesian p-values should be used for model checking"?