# Bayesian p-values, part 2: what type of information do you use for assessing whether a "Bayesian p-value" is "small enough"?

Tags: bayesian, p-value

This is a follow-up of this question: [Practical numerical example illustrating how bayesian p-values should be used for model checking?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/471079/how-do-i-judge-whether-a-bayesian-p-value-is-small-enough?noredirect=1#comment869873_471079)

- Exactly what type of information do you use for assessing whether a "Bayesian p-value" is "small enough", so that practitioners should be worried about model misfit?

Answer (score 1):

Levels/thresholds for p-values are determined based on **a pragmatic rule of thumb**.

It is a matter of weighing the relevance of type-I and type-II errors.

- **The smaller the level for p-values**, the less likely you may consider an event special and be rejecting a wrong null model.

  Which means that you are less likely to be triggered to start looking for something else when your current model is not so accurate.
- **The larger the level for p-values**, the more likely you may consider an event special and be rejecting a correct null model.

  Which means that your are too often triggered to start looking for something else or increase accuracy of experiments (since p-values are a not only dependent on the model, but also dependent on the accuracy of the experiment)

  In addition, most models are wrong anyway. Given a sufficiently large sample size we can make any null hypothesis rejected. The question is not whether a model is wrong or not, but instead whether is useful or not. Therefore, we should also look at the size of the effect and not reject anything that is only a little bit off (this relates a bit to [Lindley's/Jeffreys' paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindley%27s_paradox)). In search for 'perfect' models scientist have been focusing too much on p-values and significance.

So the reasoning for particular p-values is about weighing those two aspects and find some practical middle way.

$$\text{'less likely to reject wrong/useless model'} \\ \text{versus}\\ \text{'more likely to reject correct/useful model'}$$

P-values are arbitrary but they do relate to considerations, and these may differ depending on the field and on the time.

For instance in high energy physics you have a search [for $5\sigma$ events](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31591/origin-of-5-sigma-threshold-for-accepting-evidence-in-particle-physics) which is much higher than the typical p-values of 0.05 in other fields (which relate to a $2\sigma$ event), and also was not always that high in the past but changed with the increasing ability to make many measurements.

This means that the question regarding the assessment of 'what p-value is small/high enough' is based on a slow progression of adapting scientific standards/conventions based on pragmatic considerations, which in the end is a complex and not so exactly described process.

Comment: And while I phrased it as 'rejecting the null model' this is often interpreted as well as 'accepting the alternative model', but I guess that this interpretation is less important for Bayesian p-values, since Bayesian methods already deal with selecting hypotheses and the question is more like testing whether or not a model/approach/theory is sufficiently correct/accurate.